# why doesn't the"while" statement recognize a change in the variable?

Tags: python

I'm using the while statement to keep inputing until a condition is met but it doesn't see the change in value of the variable and keeps looping. It also starts to skip lines until it self terminates. This looks like recursion but I don't know much about that. This my code...#load

```
first = input("First lot #:   ")
last = input("Last lot #:  ")

for a in range(first,last +1):
    draw=raw_input("?:  ")

    while draw==(""):      #This is for erroneus input 
        print draw    #" while" wasn't seeing the change of value in draw so I added 
                      # print draw
        print "Error" #" print draw" is skipped after the 1st time thruogh the loop
        draw=raw_input("?:  ")
        print draw    # this line is skipped after 2nd time thruogh loop
##    
##    while draw>35:   #The same
##        print"Error"
##        draw=raw_input("?:  ")
##
##    num=(str(a),draw)
##    num=str(num)         # python thinks num is a tuple..another   
##    print num    
## 
##    f = open("pb_loader","a")
##    f.write(num)
##    f.close()
##    
##
##c=open("pb_loader","r")
##d=c.read()
##print d
##c.close()
##
```

this gets.........

```
First lot #:   1
Last lot #:  3
?:                    #entered "return"  
                      #printed empty space
Error
?:  2
2                     
?:  3                 #skipped "print draw" at top of loop
?:  3                 #skipped "print draw" at bottom of loop 
>>>                   #terminated itself
```

This seemed like very basic loop. If anyone has some insight it would be greatly apreciated

Comment: You've got two loops. What seems like the second loop acting strangly is actually the code falling through the while (because it did see the change in the variable) and going back to the outer for. After that, your inputs keep the while from executing again. Not sure why this question is deemed off-topic!

Answer (score 2):

minor indentation issue

```
first = input("First lot #:   ")
last = input("Last lot #:  ")

for a in range(first,last +1):
    draw=raw_input("?:  ")
    while draw==(""):      #This is for erroneus input 
        print "Error" #" print draw" is skipped after the 1st time thruogh the loop
        draw=raw_input("?:  ")
    print draw    # this line is skipped after 2nd time thruogh loop
```

result is

```
?:
Error
?:  1
1
?:  2
2
?:  3
3
```